# How can we make this symbol in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

**Question**: How can we make the following symbol in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) software? The color is not important, it can be just default color. But the look (position of the letters, their layout etc.) is important.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have gotten this far, using the following:

1. Font Family: Palatino Linotype
2. Font Style: Normal (this dropdown had only this option with the above font family)
3. Font size: 72
4. [Inkscape Working with text in Inkscape Kerning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3s3BkwljXY)

This is close but not quite there. For example, the top and bottom edges of `X` are not as wide as in the red image above. A foot of `E` that touches a feet of `X` is not quite as it's in red image above. Top and bottom of `E` do not have the outside edges as in the red image. Maybe someone has a better approach/suggestion etc.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is that failing? This is really kind of rudimentary knowledge for a vector application such as Inkscape.

Comment: Well.. you need to use the same font at least... That's *not* Palatino

Comment: You can read up on the design (including font choices) here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/638/site-design-ideas-updated-with-mockup . The used font is Hoefler Text https://www.typography.com/fonts/hoefler-text/characters

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to compile the following tex document `\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\TeX
\end{document}`  via latex->dvisvgm. Then you already have a svg with approximately the right kerning and vertical offfsets and you'd just have to change the font and teak letter positions a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am not suggesting you do this to recreate the TEX logo, as I have no idea if you can legally do this. To be perfectly honest I wouldn't do it.  After searching the web, I found this [SVG here](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/tex/Img/logo.svg?v=0ca861a7c12e) from the LaTeX stack exchange site. I've added this answer merely for educational purposes, since it's useful if you ever need to recreate a logo when you might only have access to a low resolution raster image.

Anyhoo, apart from the fact you aren't using the same font, I don't think you need to work with kerning to achieve something like this in Inkscape.

1. Import the original raster image into Inkscape to use as a guide
2. Type some text in a similar font, similar size, then you can convert it to paths, and ungroup the text. I used Times New Roman for this.
3. Then you can simply click and drag the letters into position.
4. Then you can remove the raster image.

Example

[image]

If you really want to get the font to look more similar, since it has already been converted to outlines, then you could edit them manually. For example editing the serifs on the T, squishing the E a touch, to make them look more similar.

[image]

Here's the result with the same colour applied.

[image]

Given enough time and care, it would be possible to tweak it further to make it virtually indistinguishable from the original, say by tweaking the E serifs, thickness of the stem, changing the angle of the thin X crossbar, etc, etc.

Comment: One could also use horizontal and vertical kerning to move the letters around.